# How can I get cost to appear correctly in Ms Project

Tags: ms-project

I'm learning MS Project and I added work resources to my project file. I added hourly rates to the work resources. I'm having an issue where when I add the work resource to a task, the task will show 0. But then when I change to a different resource and then back to the resource I want, then the cost will appear correctly. So at the moment I have been selecting the one I don't want first and then changing it. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI stack overflow is for *programming q&a*, not general computing or Office application operation.

Comment: Matt, I suggest you re-post to the Project Management group in StackOverflow. And when you do please include more information like how you "add" the resource to a task. What field are you viewing that shows the 0? How are you "changing" resources"? A screen shot of your Resource Sheet view and your Gantt Chart view would also help.